# How to remove the Google Drive Overlay Icons for Windows Files and Folders?

Tags: windows, icons, google-drive

"Google Backup and Sync" was replaced by "Google Drive for Desktop", which brought some changes.

One thing that is missing with version 51.0.9.0 is the option to disable the overlay icons on files and folders, i. e. the green checkmark when the file has been synced.

It is unnecessary for me because I see the sync activity with the active tray icon and I know which folders are synced. I do not need this "feature".

Explorer view with "Details":

[image: Google Drive sync icons windows A]

Explorer view with "Extra large icons":

[image: Google Drive sync icons windows B]

How to remove those overlay icons and have the Windows default icons back?

Comment: Do you have them in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`?

Comment: No, there is only `(Default) – REG_SZ – (value not set)`

Answer (score 2):

What works for me, go to:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

Delete the data in each google key, removing the keys/folders isn't as good as gdrive will reinstall them when it updates.

[image: registry google drive overlays]

Comment: Do I need to restart a process/my PC for this to become effective? Merely deleting the data inside the keys didn't do the trick...